# Broken Permalinks after updating from 4.9.7 to 5.3.3 on multisite

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, multisite

My client's hosting auto-updated their WordPress multisite installation to 5.3.3 from 4.9.7.
Since this happened last night, all pages on the main and subsites are 404'ing.

I have tried/verified the following based on other posts I have found:

- Resaved the permalinks. (This did update the permalinks, however, the pages still 404)
- Disabled all plugins as well as plugins individually.
- Verified the relevant directories are writeable
- No changes have been made to the `.htaccess`
- Rolled back to 4.9.7

I appreciate the help, let me know if there is any more information I can provide.

Comment: Has the PHP version been updated as well?

Comment: @TadWohlrapp Not it has not.  The site is running 5.6

Comment: Is the [Health Check plugin](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/) showing you any issues?